# how to replace value in a string based on value in another column in excel

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZIi2.jpg)

I want to replace the 'AA' in column B with corresponding values in Column A. How can I achieve that. I am looking for following results:

```
Column A
Bill
Invoice

Column B
ABAACD EFAAGH
ABAACD EFAAGH


Result
ABBILLCD EFBILLGH
ABINVOICECD EFINVOICEGH
```

Comment: In cell C1 use this formula and copy down: `=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"AA",A1)` please [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) for more information.

Comment: @tigeravatar It seems to me that your comment is a solution and not just a comment. Is there a particular reason why you posted it as such and not as a solution?

Comment: @tigeravatar  Thanks. I got what I was looking for. This solves my problem.  Actually, I was doing this    =SUBSTITUTE(B1,"AA",A1,1)  and this would replace only the first instance of "AA" removing the instance, fixed my case.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell C1 use this formula and copy it down:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"AA",A1)
```

Check out the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) for more information.

<sub>*This answer was originally posted as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103506/how-to-replace-value-in-a-string-based-on-value-in-another-column-in-excel#comment65553801_39103506) by @tigeravatar: feel free to repost this answer as your own, and leave me a comment so I'll delete this copy. This kind of answer has been stipulated for [questions with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).*</sub>